# Считается ли эта ситуация к утечке памяти?

Tags: c++, память, утечка-памяти

учусь на курсах по С++ и у меня возник вопрос про наследование - если мы приведём объект дочернего класса, который имеет свои поля(сейчас речь именно про простые переменные int,double e.t.c, c динамической памятью утечка будет, ежу понятно), к типу базового, а после удалим, вызвав тем самым деструктор базового класса, будет ли это считаться утечкой памяти, ведь память, выделенная на поля дочернего вроде как не будет освобождена

Comment: Указатель на дочернего приведём к указателю базового? Так?

Comment: Вместо мутного словестного описания следовало бы привести [mcve].

Comment: Зависит от того, что подразуметвается под "приведём объект дочернего класса ... к типу базового", и как именно выглядит класс — например, какой у него деструктор.

Answer (score 4):

Стандарт прямо говорит, что при отсутствии виртуального деструктора поведение не будет чётко определено.

> 7.6.2.9 **Delete** [expr.delete]
> In a single-object delete expression, if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type and the selected deallocation function (see below) is not a destroying operator delete, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type **shall** have a virtual destructor or the behavior is **undefined**.

```cpp
class base { };
class derived: public base { }; 

int main() {
    base* p = new derived();
    delete p; // The is undefined behavior!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Формально это неопределенное поведение всегда, независимо от типов полей.

Еще одна ситуация, в которой это создает проблемы (кроме невызванных деструкторов полей потомка) - это множественное наследование, если родитель, через которого мы удаляем, находится на ненулевом смещении в потомке:

```
struct A {int a;};
struct B {int b;};
struct C : A, B {};

int main()
{
    B *b = new C;
    delete b; // Краш!
}
```

Потому что указатель указывает не на начало блока памяти, а куда-то в середину. Виртуальный деструктор, если бы он был, исправлял бы указатель перед его освобождением.

В остальных случаях на практике это скорее всего будет работать. Но лучше все-таки избегать UB.

Comment: Там дело не в исправлении указателя, а в обращении к деструктору через vtable, которая является как бы общей для класса структурой с указателями на методы.

Comment: Т.е. по сути `ptr->vtable->destructor()`

Comment: @megorit Я не очень понял, к чему вы это. Краш здесь потому, что во `free` (или какой-то его аналог) приходит указатель на середину блока памяти, а не на начало. Наличие виртуального деструктора исправляет это, с ним во `free` попадает сдвинутый на начало указатель.

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от того, что по вашему означает *"приведём объект дочернего класса ... к типу базового, а после удалим"*. Если речь идёт о **полиморфном наследовании**, которое включает в себя наличие **таблицы виртуальных методов** (*vtable*), то оно реализуется через привденение к указателю или ссылке на базовый класс (**upcasting**). Если же вы попытаетесь скастить **не** к указателю и **не** к ссылочному типу, то вы получите **UB** (*undefined behavior*), т.е. всё что угодно.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    ~Base() { std::clog << "Base" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    ~Derived() { std::clog << "Derived" << std::endl; }
}; 

struct VrtBase {
    virtual ~VrtBase() { std::clog << "VrtBase" << std::endl; }
};

struct VrtDerived : VrtBase {
    virtual ~VrtDerived() { std::clog << "VrtDerived" << std::endl; }
}; 

int main() {
    VrtBase* vbase_ptr = new VrtDerived;
    delete vbase_ptr; // OK

    Base* base_ptr = new Derived;
    delete base_ptr; // UB

    VrtBase base1{VrtDerived{}}; // UB

    VrtBase base2;
    base2 = static_cast<VrtBase>(VrtDerived{}); // UB

    return 0;
}
```

Что касается *данных-членов* (**не** *примитивных*), то их деструктор будет вызван сразу после деструктора владеющего класса, перед деструктором базового.